# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'bookings' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO bookings 
            (book_id, 
             member_id, 
             expire_date) 
VALUES      (1, 
             3, 
             (SELECT Max(expire_date) 
              FROM   bookings 
              WHERE  member_id = 1) 
             + 5)
```

It wont let me use bookings for the second time, geez!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aniket has explained what error means. Thanks Aniket.

Your query could be converted like this:

```
INSERT INTO bookings
    (book_id, member_id, expire_date) 
SELECT
    1,3, MAX(expire_date) + INTERVAL 5 DAY
FROM bookings
WHERE member_id=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the inserted expire_date still shows 0000-00-00 ?

Comment: +1 for providing solution. You beat me by 20 secs for the answer, so I  deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL docs [subquery-errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html)

> This error occurs in cases such as the following, **which attempts to modify a table and select from the same table in the subquery**:

```
INSERT INTO bookings (book_id, member_id, expire_date) 
VALUES (1,3,(SELECT MAX(expire_date) FROM bookings WHERE member_id=1)+5)
                                            ↑
```

You can use a subquery for assignment within an [UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) because subqueries are legal in UPDATE and [DELETE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) as well as in [SELECT statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

However, you cannot use the same table (in this case, table `bookings`) for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target.